# Microsoft Graph CSharp SDK - Fetching DriveItems- paging not working, only able to retrieve 200 items out of 1000 items

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am coding against the `Microsoft Graph CSharp SDK` while testing my application for a mass collect. I noticed that there is a paging issue with my code. I added 1000 1kb files to a test OneDrive account - which I then ran my code against to see if I could access all the file. Unfortunately, I was only able to see 200 files within a single folder - not the full 1000.

I looked online and found this GitHub (now closed) [bug](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/54).

While stepping through my code I am seeing the `NextPageRequest` as being `null`. I just wanted to make sure there is no bug with this and making sure I am correctly using the `NextPageRequest`.

Code:

```
public Collection<DriveItem> GetSubItems(string id, string username)
{
    Collection<DriveItem> response = new Collection<DriveItem>();
    var retryCount = 0;

    try
    {

        response = RetryPolicy.Default.Retry<Exception, Collection<DriveItem>>(
        this.maxRetryCount,
        RetryDurationStrategies.ExponentialBackoff,
        (exception, timeSpan) =>
        {
            retryCount++;
            this.LogInfo(Strings.RetryPolicyMessage, exception.Message, timeSpan);
        },
        () =>
        {
            var driveItems = new List<DriveItem>();
            var driveItemsPage = this.GraphServiceClient.GetItemAndChildrenTask(id, username);
            var result = driveItemsPage.Result;
            driveItems.AddRange(result.Children.CurrentPage);

            while (result.Children.NextPageRequest != null)
            {
                var nextPageResult = result.Children.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
                var nextPage = nextPageResult.Result;
                driveItems.AddRange(nextPage.CurrentPage);
            }

            Collection<DriveItem> driveItemsList = new Collection<DriveItem>(driveItems);

            return driveItemsList;
        });
    }
    catch (ServiceException ex)
    {
        switch (ex.Error.Code)
        {
            case ItemNotFound:
                this.LogWarning(ex, Strings.OneDriveItemNotFound, ex.Message);
                break;
            case InvalidRequestItemId:
                this.LogWarning(ex, Strings.OneDriveUserNotFound, ex.Message);
                break;
            default:
                this.LogWarning(ex, Strings.OneDriveGenericException, ex.Message);
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (AdalServiceException ex)
    {
        switch (ex.ErrorCode)
        {
            case InvalidClient:
                this.LogWarning(ex, Strings.AdalInvalidClientErrorMsg, ex.Message);
                break;
            case UnauthorizedClient:
                this.LogWarning(ex, Strings.AdalUnauthorizedClientErrorMsg, ex.Message);
                break;
            case InvalidRequestSecret:
                this.LogWarning(ex, Strings.AdalInvalidRequestErrorMsg, ex.Message);
                break;
            default:
                this.LogWarning(ex, Strings.AdalGenericErrorMsg, ex.Message);
                break;
        }

        throw new PluginException(string.Format(Strings.AuthenticationToOneDriveWasUnsuccessful, ex.Message), ex.InnerException);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.LogWarning(ex, Strings.OneDriveGenericException, ex.Message);

        throw new PluginException(Strings.GenericPluginException, ex.InnerException);
    }

    return response;
}
```

The call to `Microsoft Graph SDK`:

```
public Task<DriveItem> GetItemAndChildrenTask(string id, string username)
{
    return this.GraphServiceClient.Drives[username].Items[id].Request().Expand(ExpandValue).GetAsync();
}
```

Below is a screen shot of the for the `result` variable:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your underlying Graph request needs to be made specifically on the children for the NextPageRequest to not be null.

```
graphServiceClient.Drives[username].Items[id].Children.Request().GetAsync();
```

If you do something like:

```
graphServiceClient.Drives[username].Items[id].Request().Expand('children').GetAsync();
```

Then the NextPageRequest will not be populated.

Comment: While this approach is a valid work around, the original code *should* work. It appears as though, for some reason, Graph does not return the `children@odata.nextlink` on the expanded collection when it should. The OneDrive API **does** return it so we'll need to figure out why Graph is behaving differently.